# Using HEC-Geo RAS

Tags: elevation, hec-ras, decimal-points

i have got some weird problems with HEC-RAS 5.0.7. and i dont know why.
Actually the heihgts are complety wrong. My terrain heights are rigth but for example my cutlines are completly useless.

My OS (Windows 10 64-Bit) uses "," as seperator instead of ".".

Could that be a problem?

I have created the terrain in ArcGIS 10.6.1 and digitized the stream, banks, flowpath and cross sections in Hec-RAS using RAS-Mapper.

[image: Cross Section - Table]

[image: Cross Section Plot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is the problem. Hec-ras works only with "." as decimal separator.

It is a pain, but that is the cost of working with old fashion but robust and reliable libraries.

I suggest you to change the setting of the machine to English (United States). Go `Control Panel` and then `Region`.

I work with the setting in the pictures, which is a bit different than pure English (United States).

[image]

[image]

Comment: after 2 hours i figured it out by myselve, but thank you anyway.